# UILabel not Removing from Superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code with the label instantiated in a getter method:

```
-(UILabel *)switchUpLabel
{
    if (!_switchUpLabel) _switchUpLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    return _switchUpLabel;
}

-(void)shouldShowSwitchupLabel:(BOOL)show
{
   if (show)
   {
      self.switchUpLabel.text = @"";
      self.switchUpLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30.0];
      [self.switchUpLabel sizeToFit];
      self.switchUpLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.center.x-self.switchUpLabel.frame.size.width/2, 10, self.switchUpLabel.frame.size.width, self.switchUpLabel.frame.size.height);
      [self.view addSubview:self.switchUpLabel];
   }
   else [self.switchUpLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

When I execute `[self.switchUpLabel removeFromSuperview];` the label remains on screen.  The only way I can get the label "off" is to do something like

```
self.switchUpLabel.text = @"";
```

A few notes:

1/ I tried adding the remove statement immediately after the add statement which should have resulted in the label not showing at all.  However, the label did show and was never removed.

2/ I verified that the label is not nil and is pointing to the same label in both cases (I output the label object to NSLog)

3/ I put the remove statement inside a main queue block to ensure it was executing on the main thread.  No difference.

Comment: Can you show your property declaration, getter code, actual excerpts from your logging, etc? There's not enough info here to debug.

Comment: Try calling `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` after removing the label.

Comment: Are you sure that you're only adding one instance of this label? It could be that you are removing one, but there's another one (or more) underneath.

Comment: rdelmar beat me to it, but the most likely cause is that you've created multiple instances of the `UILabel` and `self.switchUpLabel` only points to the last one that was created. So removing that one simply reveals the one below. You can check the number of labels with `NSLog(@"%@",self.view.subviews);`

Comment: I have included the getter method in my OP.  For debugging I added an NSLog in the add set of statements also thinking it might have been running more than once.  It does not.  I should note that the remove portion does run more than once but that should not cause an issue.  Also, as mentioned, I did try putting the remove right below the add (the next statement) so it had to be in perfect balance but it didn't remove.

Comment: Do you really have "removeFromsuperview"  (with the lowercase s) instead of "removeFromSuperview", which is the correct spelling?

Comment: No, sorry.  It was a typo as I changed the statement in the mean time to do the @"" so that it would work for now.  Of course Xcode would give an error if I mis-capitalized in the code.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hmmm... don't see how this is possible. Can you post your project, or a simplified version that demonstrates the error somewhere?

Comment: I agree it isn't logical.  Let me step through the execution again to make sure I am not missing something.  It also feels like there has to be more than once of these but the NSLog doesn't indicate that.